# Copy previous day records into the same table using entity frame work

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am struck at a point where I need to copy the previous records from the parent and its child table into its same entities.

Ex : College (Parent Table ) (Primary key enabled with identity enabled) 
Student (Child Table ) (Primary key and identity enabled )

I need to copy the previous day record in student table into next day , as he continuing in the same course . (Personnel Details will be same)

Similarly in need to copy the previous record on course table to the same table .

Can some one help me in better way of approaching this case in efcore .

Comment: Better way than what? (Better is comparative)

Comment: I am fetching the data and mapping the required fields and saving back the entity . Is there any better approach to do it like ... for both child and parent on select male the id as 0 ? Hope it’s clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var colRepo = _dbcontext.College.Single(x => x.StartDate == request.DateTime);

colRepo.Id = 0 ;

colRepo.Student.Id = 0;

colRepo.Student.collegeid = colRepo.Id ; (Foriegn Key )

_dbcontext.College.Add(colRepo)

Comment: Fancy making some heavy use of the `{}` button there, chief? This should be an edit to your question rather than an answer :)

Comment: Under your question, click EDIT, then paste the text that you pasted above (`var colRepo....`), then select it all and press the `{}` button above the text box to format it as code, then save your edit